# When is this map non surjective?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let us consider the set 
$$ M = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz = 1 \}.$$
This is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I discovered that, if $p = (p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3})$ is a point in $M$, then the tangent space to $M$ at $p$ is

$$ T_{p}M = \{ (a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 
(3(p_{1})^2 + 3p_{2}p_{3})a_{1} + (3(p_{2})^2 + 3p_{1}p_{3})a_{2} + (3(p_{3})^2 + 3p_{1}p_{2})a_{3} = 0  \}. $$

Now consider the differentiable function
$$ \pi : M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, $$ 
 $$\pi( p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3} )=p_{1}.$$
It can be shown that its differential in $p\in M$ is given by

$$ d\pi_{p}: T_{p}M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ 
$$ d\pi_{p}(a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}) = a_{1}.$$

When is this differential non surjective?

Honestly, I thought that this was always surjective.

Comment: Did you study Lagrange multipliers in your vector calculus class ? If so, apply them to find critical points of the function $\pi$ on your surface.

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether there is some point $p\in M$ where $T_pM$ is orthogonal to the $x$-axis. (To visualize this, think about projecting the circle $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2=1$ to the $x$-axis. The tangent line to the circle is vertical at points where $\partial f/\partial y = 0$.) So, here, letting $f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz$, we're asking whether we can have a point $p\in M$ with $\partial f/\partial y\,(p) = \partial f/\partial z\,(p) = 0$. After doing a bit of algebra, it seems to me that there are two such points. [Note that in your expression for $a_3$, the denominator may well vanish!]

Comment: Thank you for the clear visual insight. 
Actually, I am working out some solved exercises. My solution says that the differential $d \pi _{x}$ is not surjective iff it is the zero map and, in order to make it happen, that $x \in M $ has to be such that $T_{x}M = \{ (0, a_{2}, a_{3})  \forall  a_{2}, a_{3} \in \mathbb{R} \}$ 
This sounds meaningless to me and I am not able to relate it to your explanation.

Comment: As you should have learned in multivariable calculus, the *normal* vector to the tangent plane at $p$ of the level surface $f(x,y,z)=\text{constant}$ is the gradient vector $\nabla f(p)$.